# Getting Bad request Error for Ajax call in Spring MVC

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting Bad Request Error for my ajax call in Spring MVC. Please refer the code below and kindly comment on this :

ajax call :

```
 $.getJSON('deletRowRequest', {ticketId: ids}, function(data){
        alert(data); 
 });
```

controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/deletRowRequest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List deleteRow(Model model, @RequestParam(value="ticketId")  String ticketId){
    String[] ticketString = ticketId.split(",");
    String flag = "deleteRow";
    List deleteTicketList =  new ArrayList();
    for(String tick :ticketString){
        deleteTicketList.add(tick);
    }
    System.out.println("list>> "+deleteTicketList);
    UpdateDB updatedb =  new UpdateDB();
    updatedb.updateTable(deleteTicketList, flag);
    List ticket =  updatedb.getRecordsFromDB();
    System.out.println(ticket);

    return ticket;
}
```

I have also included Jackson 1.7.4 jars in the lib folder and `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in my servlet.

Please guide me solve this problem.

Comment: Are you also using Spring Security?

Comment: No i am not using any thing like this

Comment: Probably `ids` is undefined. Check its value before firing the request.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling String that ticketId is a request param. So spring search for a param in the query string with the name ticketId.

But you're sending ticketId as part of the body of the request.

You have 2 optinos.

1. Change the invokation, and include your ticketid as part of the querystring.
2. Change the Spring method, so it could receive the ticketid as part of the body request. You can use @RequestBody instead of @RequestParam.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), the data (second parameter) is sent to the server as part of the query string. It is not written to the request body.

Comment: "A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request." It doesn't say as part of querystring

Comment: "Data that is sent to the server is appended to the URL as a query string. If the value of the data parameter is a plain object, it is converted to a string and url-encoded before it is appended to the URL." Please read the whole section.